# Как исправить ошибку ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested?

Tags: sql, oracle

Уже в течении месяца я использовал Oracle APEX VM. После очередной активации виртуальной машины, я попытался осуществить подключение к системному пользователю `system`. Результатом подключения стала данная ошибка, из-за которой я не могу подключиться к своей БД.

Как исправить эту ошибку?

Comment: См. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16049014/10138734

Comment: @Akina, Я последовал вашей рекомендации, но это не решает мою проблему: виртуальная машина у меня на linux и на ней нет файла tnsnames, который было бы нужно изменить.

Comment: Обратите внимание - я дал совет через 3 минуты. Это означает, что всего 3 минуты надо было, чтобы увидеть вопрос, прочитать, сделать поиск по SO и запостить вариант решения. А количество плюсов у ответа по ссылке однозначно говорит, что проблема - нередкая, то есть найти решение с уточнениями - не так уж и сложно. Попробуйте, должно получиться.

Comment: @Akina, вы абсолютно правы! Я уже нашёл нужный файл и открыл его для редактирования, но не знаю пока, что именно мне в нём нужно изменить.

Comment: А вот тут я пас - нет у меня оракла, и никогда не было. Но, с другой стороны, не может быть, чтобы "оно само". гарантирую, что между "последний раз работало" и "вдруг перестало" что-то было сделано. И скорее всего, за пределами Oracle, но влияющее на разрешение имён хостов или сервисов.

Comment: @Akina, Понял. Благодарю вас за помощь!

Comment: _но не знаю пока, что именно мне в нём нужно изменить_, пока ничего не надо менять. Покажите как вы подключаетесь. Проверьте командой `lsnrctl status`, имя сервиса, с которым вы подключаетесь, зарегестрировано.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Эту ошибка означaет, что прослушивателю не известно имя сервиса, к которому идёт подключение.

Или оно дествительно неверно:

```
$ sqlplus -l me/me@dbserver:1521/pdb1xxx

ERROR:
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect
descriptor
```

Или имя сервиса не зарегестрированно на прослушивателе. Проверить можно так:

```
$ lsnrctl status|grep pdb1
Service "pdb1" has 2 instance(s).
```

Если ничего не выводит, то существует множество причин этого. Но если вчера работало, а сегодня нет, и никто ничего не менял, то причина скорее всего одна: БД не стартовала.

Comment: Благодарен вам за ответ! В моём случае база данных работала исправно и я только делал в ней какие-либо таблицы, да пользователей создавал. А вчера был неприятно удивлён тем фактом, что даже к системному пользователю подключиться не могу. Пришлось сносить виртуальную машину и ставить по новой - а это уже совсем другая история и совсем другие проблемы. Спасибо вам за то, что пытаетесь помочь!